# Unable to initialize firebase project using firebase-tools

Tags: firebase-tools

I'm trying to initialize a firebase project using the command `firebase init`, but I get the message `Error: Command requires authentication, please run firebase login`.
When I run `firebase login`, the process hangs and does not return the prompt :

[image]

Previously I have installed the latest stable version of **node.js** and **firebase-tools** (with `npm install -g firebase-tools`). I'm using a Windows 8.1 x64 machine.

The content of **firebase-debug.log** file noes not report any error or warning:

```
[debug] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] Command:      C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\      \AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\bin\firebase login
[debug] Platform:     win32
[debug] Node Version: v5.1.0
[debug] Time:         Mon Nov 23 2015 13:49:06 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
[debug] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug]
```

How can I debug the login command? Nomaly it should open a browser window for authentication, but this does't happen in my case.

Comment: I've tested this on another machine that does not have a proxy and it's working. How do I set the proxy for firebase-tools ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Did you get your answer yet?

You need to type 'firebase login --interactive' then it'll take you through the browser to a gmail account to sign into then you can execute your 'firebase init' command.

Comment: Thanks a million!!